# Confusion on grep pattern search

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Consider this log file

```
SN      PID     Date                            Status
1       P01     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
2       P02     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
3       P03     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
4       P04     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
5       P05     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
6       P06     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
7       P07     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
8       P08     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
9       P09     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
10      P010    Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
```

When i do =>  `grep  "P01" File`
output is : (*as expected*)

```
1       P01     Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
10      P010    Fri Feb 14 19:32:36 IST 2014    Alive
```

**But** when i do => `grep  " P01 " File` (*notice the space before and after **P01***)

I do not get any output!

**Question :** `grep` matches pattern in a line, so " P01 " ( *with space around* ) should match the first PID of P01 as it has spaces around it....but seems that this logic is wrong....what obvious thing i am missing here!!!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the log uses tabs not spaces, your grep pattern won't match. I would add word boundaries to the word you want to find:

```
grep '\<P01\>' file
```

If you really want to use whitespace in your pattern, use one of:

```
grep '[[:blank:]]P01[[:blank:]]' file    # horizontal whitespace, tabs and spaces
grep -P '\sP01\s' file                   # using Perl regex
```

Comment: yeah,its a `tab-space`, so `tab-space` is considered different from a `white-space` in grep???

Comment: Generally "whitespace" is meant to include space, tab, newline, carriage return, backspace, vertical tab. A tab is a different character than space, so yes, grep treats them differently. The character class `[[:space:]]` is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\b\v]` and the character class `[[:blank:]]` is equivalent to `[ \t]` (I think that's close to correct...) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii

Comment: Further investigation: `\b` is not included in `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Further reading: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions

Comment: thankx for ref... :)   considering your knowledge, one minor question sir, to get line of PID `P010`, I tried `grep "P0.*0$" FILE` but it didn't worked, can i do word pattern search using `grep` for `PID` or even in general sense???

Comment: @NoobEditor It didn't work because of the `$` in your pattern.  `$` is a regex metacharacter denoting end of string.  `grep "P0[0-9]*0" file` would be one example that might work for you.

Comment: Note that the pattern `P0[0-9]*0` will also match `P001` -- the `*` quantifier means "**zero** or more of the previous atom". If you want "P followed by 0 followed by one or more digits followed by 0, end of the word", use `'P0[0-9]+0\>'`

Comment: @glennjackman : so `\<` is equivalent to `^` and `\>` to `$` for word search in grep....??

Comment: Yes: `^` and `$` are **line** anchors; `\<` and `\>` are **word** anchors